# How to delete all files and folders in given folder except one and folder itself?

Tags: bash

I currently use following, but `dist` folder is also deleted.

```bash
find ./dist ! -name '.borgignore' -prune -exec rm -r {} +
```

I am aware of `./dist/*`, but also want to delete dot files.

Comment: Dont use `-r`!!

Comment: You probably just want `-type f`, but it's not clear what you want to do with other directories.

Comment: It isn't clear, from your `find` command, what you're trying to achieve. `rm -r` will remove directories and their contents _recursively_. If you want to delete only regular files, use `-type f` in your `find` command. Dot files won't be hidden from `find`.

Comment: I just updated question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: You can use `find ./dist -mindepth 1 ....` to exclude the `dist` directory itself

Comment: @WilliamPursell I updated question… do you still recommend not using `-r`? If so, what is the alternative? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Some versions of find support `-delete`, on others use some variant of `-depth` along with `rm` (without `-r`)

Comment: Thanks for helping out! `find ./dist ! -name '.borgignore' -delete` works beautifully on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `GLOBIGNORE`, a plain `bash` feature:

```bash
$ GLOBIGNORE=./dist/.borgignore
$ printf '%s\n' ./dist/*
```

Check the output and if it's OK:

```bash
$ rm -rf ./dist/*
```

Explanations: when `GLOBIGNORE` is set to a colon-separated list of patterns, pathname expansion ignores the files that also match one of the patterns, and the `dotglob` option is automatically enabled: that is, dot-files match the `./dist/*` pattern, except the `./dist/.` and `./dist/..` filenames (they would have to be listed explicitly to match).